# How to get zero as default value of Core Data sum?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm building an expense tracker app to learn Core Data. My expenses are organized into categories which are displayed in the home screen in a collection view. Each cell has the name of the category and the daily total of the expenses under it.

My collection view is reorderable and I can change the order of my categories in the managed object context, but I can't do the same for the totals. To get the totals, I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` built like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([SPRExpense class]) inManagedObjectContext:[SPRManagedDocument sharedDocument].managedObjectContext];
fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription;

NSDate *startDate, *endDate;

// Get the 00:00 and 23:59 of the current date here...

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateSpent >= %@ AND dateSpent <= %@", startDate, endDate];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

NSExpressionDescription *totalColumn = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
totalColumn.name = @"total";
totalColumn.expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"@sum.amount"];
totalColumn.expressionResultType = NSDecimalAttributeType;

fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[totalColumn];
fetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = @[@"category"];
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"category.displayOrder" ascending:YES];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[SPRManagedDocument sharedDocument].managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
```

However, when I do `fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects`, it only returns the totals for the categories that have expenses listed under them within the day. That is a problem when reordering my categories because the `fetchedObjects` count isn't the same as the number of my categories.

Can I modify my fetched results controller to return zero as the sum if there is nothing to sum in the category?

Comment: I feel like you should just be able to add an `OR @0` to your expression, but I can't say it'll actually work.

Comment: @stevesliva Nope, doesn't work.

Comment: I think that makes sense.  Rather than fixing the fetch, could you overload something like dateSpent to return zero.  Or wrap dateSpent for this fetch?  ie make the model objects play better.